# ALSA error shown when instatiating sr.Microphone()

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio, alsa

I am trying to make a small speech recognition app using Tkinter and speech_recognition. I am able to instantiate the recognizer object, but when i try to instantiate the microphone object, i get these ALSA errors. I have no idea what to do, as they are not standard Python tracebacks. I am using Ubuntu.

code:

```
     self.window = tkinter.Tk(className=" Speech Recognition App")
        self.window.geometry("640x480")
        self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        self.microphone = sr.Microphone()
        self.draw_main_window()
```

errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
```

Any help is appreciated!